# Using Port DD as GPIO on MCF5282

Tags: embedded, freescale

I’ve got a MCF5282 that I’m trying to use PDD4 as a GPIO on.  In my setup code, I’ve got:

```
MCF5282_GPIO_DDRDD = 0x10;    /* cs on dd4. */
MCF5282_GPIO_PORTDD = 0x10; /* active-low. */
```

And in my main loop, I’ve got:

```
for( mainloop_cnt = 0; true; mainloop_cnt++ )
{
    MCF5282_GPIO_PORTDD = (mainloop_cnt & 0x10);
    /* other stuff. */
}
```

Which should give me a nice square wave on the oscilloscope, but the port doesn’t seem to be doing as I say.  Am I missing some setup steps?  I can’t find anything in the 5282 manual about a “Port DD pin-assignment register” to repurpose it from its “primary” role as DDATA.

Comment: Not everyone on the site celebrates Christmas, but there are significantly fewer people around right now. It may take a bit for you to get your answer, sorry for the delay.

Comment: @Kortuk, I expect that, but still better to get the question out there now so it's around when people get back.  I'll poke it with a meaningless edit if nobody's answered by Monday.

Comment: Just making sure you knew why people were not jumping on your question.

Comment: Does `mainloop_cnt` toggle? Can you post complete code that shows this behaviour?

Comment: @tyblu, mainloop_cnt increments each time through the loop.  I've added the for-loop used as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datasheet makes it sound like you need to disconnect the on-chip debugger from port DD before you can use it as a normal port.

> ### 26.4 Functional Description
>
> #### 26.4.1 Overview
>
> [...]
>
> In single-chip mode, all pins are configured as digital I/O by default, except for debug data pins (DDATA[3:0]) and processor status pins (PST[3:0]). These pins are configured for their primary functions by default in all modes.

— *[MCF5282 and MCF5216 ColdFire Microcontroller User’s Manual, Rev. 3](http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/ref_manual/MCF5282UM.pdf?pspll=1), § 26, p. 27*

In most MCUs I've used, alternate functions usually override GPIOs, which has the lowest priority.

Comment: We never figured this out (we ended up using another pin for the GPIO), but your explanation is the only one I've heard that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

is mainloop_cnt correctly declared as an unsigned char?
(can't comment anywhere yet, sorry)

Comment: It currently looks like MCF5282_GPIO_PORTDD should be toggling between 0x10 and 0x00, every sixteen iterations. You're not getting any output?